# Function won't remember variable

Tags: javascript, function, variables, global-variables, var

I want to create a scoreboard using javascript. I've created a global variable that is `NaN`. I've also created a function with an `if` statement. If the variable is `NaN`, then the variable needs to be 0. The variable will then get a +1. When I click on the button to run the function, the result is 1. But when I reclick the button and rerun the function, it stays 1 and doesn't add the +1. Can anybody tell me what I'm doing wrong?

```
var score = score; //creates a global variable
function addscore(score) {
    alert(score); // just for me to see what value the variable has
    if ((score) = isNaN) {
        var score = 0; // the variable will be a number
    }
    score++;
    alert(score);
}
```

Comment: `var score = score; //creates a global variable` --- o_O

Comment: `var score = score` Plot twist: This *does not* create a global variable.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By making `score` a parameter of your function, you are declaring a local variable. Your function operates on this local variable instead of the global, so you have to pass it a value every time you call it.

Just remove `score` from the function declaration:

```
function addscore() {
```

Also, this line doesn't make sense:

```
var score = score;
```

You can't set `score` to `score` because `score` doesn't exist yet! Just do:

```
var score = 0;
```

And `if ((score) = NaN) {` will assign a value to score. You want to check the values, like this `if (isNaN(score)) {`.

Comment: I've also changed var score = 0; to score = 0; in the if statement, which made the function work.

Comment: @gloo Yes, I missed that one. Glad it helped!

Comment: But in JavaScript, NaN !== NaN. You need to use the global isNaN() function to check for NaN.

Comment: @simonlchilds You're absolutely correct. Wrote this answer on my phone and wasn't thinking clearly. Edited.

Answer (score 0):

`function addscore` is the reason of your misery. You added the variable `score` inside it, which the if condition will refer to instead of the global variable. Remove it. Your function definition should look somthing like the following

```
function addscore() {
....
....
}
```

Also for comparison in your if condition use `==` instead of `=`, which is for assignments. 
Change line

```
var score = score; //creates a global variable
```

to something like

```
var score = 0; //creates a global variable
```

as score does not exist as of yet.